# Get text between this and next known element

Tags: jquery

Can anyone please tell what I am doing wrong with the following code?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="rinput">$100 <br>
      <input type="radio" name="rinput">$200 <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
$('table').click(function () {
  $('input[type="radio"]').each(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      var text = $(this).nextUntil('br').text();
      alert(text);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Basically I am trying to get text between current element "$(this)" and next element "br" if it's checked.

http://jsfiddle.net/wu3bf/

Comment: Why not to use value in your input ?

Comment: actually I don't have access to the source code directly. This is why I am using jQuery approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How is this? No HTML change neccessary:

```
$('table').click(function () {
  text = $('input[type=radio][name=rinput]:checked')[0].nextSibling.nodeValue;
  alert(text);
});
```

By the way, since there is only going to be one checkbox with the `name=rinput` checked at once, your `each()` method is redundant. I've used `[name=rinput]:checked` in your selector instead.

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/wu3bf/11/)

Comment: Glad to have helped you (:

Comment: It happens to us all!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using value attribute i think you can easily get the value using jquery

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="rinput" value="$100"> <br>
      <input type="radio" name="rinput" value="$200"> <br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: He commented that he can't change the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` is your input, `.nextUntil('br')` get the input and br and not the text node, `.text()` get the content text of the input and the br.

If you really wanna go this way, put your text in spans or any other element.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="rinput"><span>$100</span><br>
      <input type="radio" name="rinput"><span>$200</span><br>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
$('table').click(function () {
  $('input[type="radio"]').each(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      var text = $(this).nextUntil('br').text();
      alert(text);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

But i would also use value attribute.